# Scale Invariant of the Navier Stokes equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

In incompressible 3d Navier-Stokes equations (NSE):

$$
\partial_{t}u-\Delta u+u\cdot\nabla u+\nabla p=0,
$$
if we set 
$u\left(x,t\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}U\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{t}}\right), $
then 
$$
\Delta U+\frac{x}{2}\cdot\nabla U+\frac{1}{2}U-U\cdot\nabla U+\nabla P=0?\quad (1)
$$

I've calculate that:

$$
\partial_{t}u=\frac{1}{t}\left(-\frac{x}{2t}\nabla U-\frac{U}{2\sqrt{t}}\right),\quad\Delta u=\frac{1}{\sqrt{t^{3}}}\left(\Delta U\right),\quad u\cdot\nabla u=\frac{1}{\sqrt{t^{3}}}U\cdot\nabla U.
$$

then I get another equation:

$$
\Delta U+\frac{x}{2\sqrt{t}}\cdot\nabla U+\frac{1}{2}U-U\cdot\nabla U+\nabla P=0,
$$

which is not the same as (1). If there is something wrong in my calculation?

[Reference here (formula 1.2)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1306.2136.pdf)

Comment: Your calculation is correct. I think what the authors mean (perhaps) is that $x$ is replaced by $x/\sqrt{t}$.

Comment: oh, yes, It's reasonable, I didn't realize it in this direction. thank you.

Comment: What you calculated is true when you write $x/\sqrt t$ as the variable of $U$.